# Data Validation in Hive

Tags: python, validation, hadoop, hive, bigdata

In our application we are migrating huge volume of data from teradata to Hive. 
Need to validate the data between source and target.We are planning to do it using python & pandas dataframe. 
My queries are

```
1.Will pandas data-frame can handle around 15 million of data ? 
2.Is there any other way to do it ?
```

What is the best way to achieve the above using python ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dataframe can handle the data it all depend on the how much memory and free resource/executors  you have.

Comment: What exactly are you trying as a part of validation? is it validate whether the dataset has been migrated successfully or not?

Comment: Thanks Dinesh&Squid. We are validating column name,data types and the data whether its migrated successfully or not.